# Package explorer not showing...packages, in Eclipse. How to fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse, package-explorer

By some reason, it seems my Package Explorer is showing the folder structure of my project instead of its package structure. How would I go about "fixing" this? I've tried playing with the filters but it seemed of no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess the problem lied with other unrelated thing. It seems like it wasn't considering this to be a Java Project, at least it wouldn't allow me to use the refactoring capabilities.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you configure the corresponding folders to be the source folder?

They should be included in the java build path (**The project properties--> java build path --> source** )  . Eclipse only shows the package structure and provides the necessary stuff such as refactoring capabilities , checking java syntax error for the folders that are included in the java build path.

Comment: I commited my project to Git, then cloned it from another computer. Now path entries are missing, and the actual ones not there (and thus not showing as packages). Did I do something wrong during commiting?

Answer (score 22):

[image]

From the menu pointed in the image, setting `Package Presentation` as `flat` may solve your problem.

Edit: Pointed menu is also available in `Package Explorer` view.

Answer (score 6):

Navigate-> Show In -> Package Explorer

Answer (score 5):

Right Click on your top level of your package, go to **build path->use as source folder**. Will show you what you want.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Eclipse neon, just click on the top right corner button(The one near the bug icon). [image]

When you hover over it, hint says 'Java'.
That should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the folder was already in the build path.

But Excluded was set to **

After I set it to (None) using the remove button it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps are OK for my teammate :

project properties -> Project Facets -> tick EAR(version 1.3)

Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

just follow the below in your Project Explorer !!

1.project presentation --> flat (click Pic 1 & 2 to see images)

2.Top level Elements -->Projects

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdbkK.png)
[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCJ6G.png)

Answer (score 1):

Click on menu view of project explorer -> select working set-> manually select all set.

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all the above. I deleted the project from eclipse. Restarted eclipse. Re-imported my maven projects and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Suite Go to **Window --> Show View --> Project Explore**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Me *Spring Tool Suite 4*

> Version: 4.7.2.RELEASE

> Build Id: 202009020958 `

There is a back arrow in the project explorer - just click , it solved my issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem in Eclipse Spring Tools IDE. This is what i tried it worked for maven project

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

File > Open projects from file system > directory

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZRmm.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E75oD.png)